# Why don't if statements work with my boolean arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What I'm trying to do here is to always get a random value from my String arraylist and to do this I'm using another arraylist containing the same amount of booleans as the strings.

When I need a random string I do this:

```
randomstring = r.nextInt(100);
String mystring = c.getAnswear(randomstring);

if(c.getAnswear(randomstring) == null){
    randomstring = r.nextInt(100);
    mystring = c.getAnswear(randomstring);
    System.out.println("Random again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

And this is how it looks inside c.getAnswear

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("blablabla");
//And another 100 of theese
//Then we have theese boolean array
ArrayList<Boolean> trueornot = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
trueornot.add(false);
//Another 100 of them
//Then we have this
String Answear = null;
if(trueornot.get(indexNum).equals(true)){
   Answear = null;
   System.out.println(Answear);
   System.out.println("Already used string random again!");
}
else if(trueornot.get(indexNum).equals(false)){
    trueornot.add(indexNum, true);
    Answear = strings.get(indexNum);
    System.out.println(Answear);
    System.out.println("Something in the array was set to true");
}
return Answear;
```

But when I try to do this can randomize my string how much I want and it prints to console something was set to true but I see many times the same string gets used again and the `System.out.println("Already used string random again!");` never gets printed in the console

Same with when I call this getAnswear I have the if statement `(c.getAnswear(randomstring) == null)` the line inside there `System.out.println("random again!!!!!!!");` never gets into the console.

How would I make it work? Seems like the answer string inside `getAnswear` is never null and that's strange because I'm setting the booleans to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trueornot.add(indexNum, true)`
this adds the value to the list and shifts the previous value at that index down the list.

you should use `trueornot.set(...)` which replaces the value...

update:

> And this is how it looks inside c.getAnswear

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

strings.add("blablabla");

//And another 100 of theese
//Then we have theese boolean array

ArrayList<Boolean> trueornot = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

trueornot.add(false);

//Another 100 of them
//Then we have this
```

if this actually happens every time getAnswer is called then you're recreating the strings and the boolean list everytime, all previous changes are lost.
`strings` and `trueornot` should be class fields and not local variables.

Comment: I did use trueornot.set() before but it happend the same thing as it does not.. I was just trying it out with .add

Comment: Oh.. This is true, But i can't put it outside this method and i can't also create it inside another method.

Comment: you must if you want any changes to persist in subsequent calls.

Comment: I can't initiate Arraylist in the class fields

Comment: perform the initialization in the constructor of the class

Answer (score 2):

may it be, you want to set your value true, instead of insert it?

you do this:

```
trueornot.add(indexNum, true);
```

but to set a value you have to do this:

```
trueornot.set(indexNum, true);
```

Comment: Same as i commented on the other answear saying this I did use trueornot.set() before but it happend the same thing as it does not.. I was just trying it out with .add

Comment: I didnt see that answer, when i posted mine ^^